# Установка AlphaForm в delphi 7 закончилась провалом

Tags: delphi

Проблема такая - при выборе компонента (папки ) в sourse > envirment Options>libaru, выбираем libaru path и путь   C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Source\acnt_reg7\D7 при добавлении всё норм, далее нужно file  open, войти   в папку C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Source\acnt_reg7\D7 выбрать acntD7.dpk , далее всё ок и окошко с заголовком Package - acntD7.dbk . Нажимаем компиль, всё норм , а дальше подвох с install , когда на него нажимаешь вылезают две ошибки Окно с заколовком "Delphi 7 : delphi32.exe - Не удалось найти компонент" Далее текст окошка - Приложению не удалось запустиься, поскольку acntD7_R.bpl не был найден. Повторная установка приложения может исправить эту проблему. - По середине клавиша OK , жмём её и вторая ошибка - с заголовком "Error" текст -  Cant't load package C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\acntD7.bpl . Ну я та монял и бегом в эту папку смотреть что не так открываю и нахожу этот модуль acntD7.bpl присутствует и весит 363 килобайта и также присутствует acntD7_R.bpl весом 1500 килобайт... Вопрос, что не так когда этот фаил есть. Почему ошибка вылезает а фаил есть? Почему не ставиться у кого была такая проблема помогите плиз, буду благодарен...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пути надо пропиывать и в Browsing Path, и в Library Path. К исходникам/dcu и к bpl и т.д.
run-time'ий пакет установить в менеджере пакетов(Вроде Component -> Pachages...), продварительно удалив оттуда уже существующий.

Comment: Всё так и было сделано, не выходит .

Comment: Повторял на другой машине таг-же не выходит, и всё-таки как это так фаил есть а его типа нету... Как в том фильме "Видишь суслика , нет , а он есть". Эту подобную проблему я встречал в загрузчике windows только как устранить не понял , по верх той системы поставил ... .

Comment: Не правильно пути указываешь, как уже было сказанно. В архиве ищи файл с инструкцией

Comment: Спасибо !!!! Это моя ошибка сори.